# r plotting on wrong scale

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
         time ctrl_lsm1_stat     id     ratio
ABP140.1    1             no ABP140 -0.262682
ARI1.1      1             no   ARI1 -0.163952
BPH1.1      1             no   BPH1 -0.517519
BUR6.1      1            yes   BUR6  0.645573
CDC20.1     1             no  CDC20 -0.264072
CLB2.1      1             no   CLB2 0.0690172
```

But when I try to plot it using this code:

```
plot(d2$time, d2$ratio, col=ifelse(d2$ctrl_lsm1_stat=="yes",1,2),cex=2.0)
```

I get this output:

[image]

Can anyone tell me why R is messing up the ratio values and why are they constantly increasing? The largest ratio value in my dataset is 3.63236 and the smallest is -0.0153141, so the scale should be between those values.

Comment: check `range(d2$ratio)`? does it match your dataset?

Comment: Your code generates another plot in my R and values are ok.

Comment: yeah it definitely matches my dataset. i have no idea whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

so I figured it out. It was as simple as adding `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to my `read.table`